# How can Spark avoid Multithreaded conflict while submitting stage

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to write a program which can deal with the DAG schedule, and I met a problem that when two child success at the same time, the parent may be executed repeatly. So I referred to spark's design, but I didn't find where spark deal with this situation.

```
/** Submits stage, but first recursively submits any missing parents. */
  private def submitStage(stage: Stage) {
    val jobId = activeJobForStage(stage)
    if (jobId.isDefined) {
      logDebug("submitStage(" + stage + ")")
      if (!waitingStages(stage) && !runningStages(stage) && !failedStages(stage)) {
        val missing = getMissingParentStages(stage).sortBy(_.id)
        logDebug("missing: " + missing)
        if (missing.isEmpty) {
          logInfo("Submitting " + stage + " (" + stage.rdd + "), which has no missing parents")
          submitMissingTasks(stage, jobId.get)
        } else {
          for (parent <- missing) {
            submitStage(parent)
          }
          waitingStages += stage
        }
      }
    } else {
      abortStage(stage, "No active job for stage " + stage.id, None)
    }
  }
```

Did I miss something?